# How can I power a 120V 50A water heater?

Tags: shower, water-heater

I have an electric shower head water heater. If you only have a cold water feed, it’s a great gizmo to have. The problem has been the proper current to operate it. It says it requires 110V 4800W 50A 50/60HZ

I installed it directly to my wall plug in bathroom. First it tripped my breakers. I stopped using it. The electrical wall plug felt hot too.

So, now I’m wondering what I have to do to use this thing. Is there like a mechanism, like converter or current stabilizer, that I could plug the shower head into instead of plugging it to the wall?

Running a separate cable directly to to my breakers is not an option. Also just installing a bigger breaker doesn’t seem like a good option either because my wall plug unit got hot.

Is there a product that could help me?

Thanks,

Vic

I am adding photos to clarify my issue. I would like an option to NOT having to run cable directly to box. I do admit it doesn’t seem likely that I have any option.

[image][image][image]

Comment: Heating water takes a lot of energy, and if you are in the USA, our 120v power generally isn't up to the task for these instant point of use heaters unless a specific high-current circuit is run.  Even if there was a device to cut the power usage of the heater, it would no longer heat the water (very much).

Comment: Your wall plug is only for 1200 watts, it will get very hot trying it 4800w(flames hot).  I am surprise it does not require 220/240 volt circuit.  A picture or make and model of shower heater will help.

Comment: More information, please. Update your post with a model number or photos. That's a very odd set of specs. Most appliances that draw 50A are 240v. They certainly won't have a standard plug that would interface with a bathroom outlet. #danger #unregulatedgizmo

Comment: `only have a cold water feed` ... what does that mean? ... why is it not possible to run a hot line?

Comment: If it were really a 4800W @ 240V device, running it on 120V would draw only 12A (and produce only 1440W). It would be ineffective but it probably wouldn’t trip the breaker.

Comment: "Running a separate cable directly to to my breakers is not an option"   Why not?

Comment: Can’t get there from here.  Water heating  takes way more power than common sockets have.

Comment: This has been closed, but you can still [edit] it to add more details, as requested, and it will go into a queue to be reviewed for reopening. All is not lost, don't give up hope, just supply some more details and you'll get the help you need.

Comment: Not UL listed! And you're going to trust that in your shower with water?

Comment: This looks like a really bad idea

Comment: Yes I’m going to trust it haha it works in many homes overseas. Understood that it may not work here. I was really hoping that some sort of power supply could provide the necessary power. Running a separate line would break certain rules that I don’t want to break. If there is no line power supply (not generator) that I can use, then the shower head will not be used.

Answer (score 3):

The thing draws 50A.  There's no way it will work on any circuit that wasn't designed to supply (at least) 50A.  So that means a separate cable back to the breaker panel, and a dedicated breaker.  No magic stabilizer is going to get around that.

The only alternatives are going to be impractical, such as installing a large generator in the shower room.

Comment: It shouldn’t draw 50A at ~120V; at 4800W it should be 40A - needing a 50A circuit after 20% derating.